# Building / making PyQt5

Tags: make, ubuntu-14.04, pyqt

I'm trying to build PyQt5 on Ubuntu 14.04; I've [downloaded the tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.2.1/PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz), unpacked, and run:

```
python configure --sip-incdir /home/chris/sip/sip-4.15.5/siplib
make
```

`Configure` finishes fine (`--sip-incdir` is where I installed sip), but `make` does't complete, with several errors such as the following:

```
 error: ‘SubdomainSetting’ is not a member of ‘QWebSecurityOrigin’
     QWebSecurityOrigin::SubdomainSetting a2;
```

([full list of errors from output on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RiZa0hpD)). Any ideas on how to fix are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is some python3-pyqt5 packages for your distribution: (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-pyqt5). Maybe simpler to install it this way.

Also, maybe you want to use the "python" command, probably calls a wrong version of python (check if you have only one version or more and if this is the version needed by pyqt5).

For example, I had to compile/install two times: one for python-2.7, and an other for python-3.4. I use PyQT5 with python-3.4 and PyQT4 with python-2.7.
For call the good command python, I would use in your case: python3.4 configure.

If this doesn't work, I think there are some compatibility problems.

In this case, just check all and go back to the first step installation (from all packages needed: python, QT, and dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have an easier time of it if instead of trying to build PyQt5 from the PyQt-gpl-5.2.1.tar.gz archive, you install PyQt5 version 5.2.1 (same version) directly from the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

PyQt5 exposes the Qt5 API to Python 3. This package contains the following modules: QtCore, QtDBus, QtDesigner, QtGui, QtHelp, QtNetwork, QtPrintSupport, QtTest and QtWidgets.

To also install the development files for PyQt5:

```
sudo apt install pyqt5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the patched PyQt5 from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/pyqt5/trusty/tarball/14?start_revid=14 (or with `bzr branch lp:ubuntu/trusty/pyqt5`), and run `configure.py` with Python 2.

I also had sip (`python-sip-dev`) installed with apt-get so I used `python configure.py --sip-incdir=/usr/include/python2.7` instead.